# How to decode saml 1.0 response (no xml) with php

Tags: php, xml, decode, saml

I'm new to SSO and never worked with SAML, so that's why I'm asking this question here.

When I try to log in into the SSO system, they are forwarded to my website with the following values in the $_POST

Note that I sometimes added 3 dots to reduce the lenght of the wresult in my question here.

```
array(3) {
  ["wa"]=>
  string(10) "wsignin1.0"
  ["wresult"]=>
  string(6554)     "2016-10-21T07:09:29.009Z2016-10-21T08:09:29.009Zhttp://...be/http://...be/urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearerdk-superadminNvEoboAZrZs+burRB+776E+lXYc5IWsuWVktpHsyfh8=c37VIVxu0D0yHMOW9pk5XCPcTs8Mb+maOoBsldhASO2mjEnd98jC2ibTRtYaaI2MDMmUTfdbo8Z1nqIyTGjklZ/+coJ2C8wduSTj...Q5mH4c3epYj7z5zXdpzQhGTXKAc9/uYvsc3ZpEKPC9Xgdi3XFexbEWWgsMevxRz3s1G6HsbTgCrA0VKz1D9EuWRwb8jnfpqRTR6d_a1afcc4c-cb1e-4c0d-9c42-87cfb446f8b6_a1afcc4c-cb1e-4c0d-9c42-87cfb446f8b6urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertionhttp://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Issuehttp://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer"
  ["wctx"]=>
  string(8) "ssologon"
}
```

Looking on the internet, I would expect getting an XML. Is this encoded XML? How can I decode it?
SSO is done with ADFS and I also received a fingerprint key, not sure when and how to use it.

I hope someone can explain this a little to me.

Comment: [SAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0) is an XML based format. I would expect the `wresult` to be an XML. Check the source view of your browser.

Comment: @ThW: Thanks for your comment. It really seems to be XML looking into the source. This helped me out a lot!